# Transformar una string a una cadena de bytes en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hola bueno mi duda es simple pero quiero poder adjuntar un int a una 2 string y para eso las quiero trasformar a una cadena de valores hexadecimales para que quedara algo asi

```
// int = 1 | string1 = 'AAAA' | string2 = 'BBBB'
data = '/x01/x41/x41/x41/x41/x42/x42/x42/x42/'
```

Para eso estoy usando python 2.7 y quiero usar la librería de struct con la funcion struct.pack pero e intentado de muchas maneras y obviamente ni una funciona por ejemplo esta

```
data = struct.pack_into('I cccc cccc', 5, 'AAAA', 'BBBB' )
```

pero no funciona porque dice que espera 9 valores y recibe 3 porque obviamente una string cuanta solo como una varible, en fin alguien me podría ayudar con este problema, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar `c` usa `s` en el formato del struct para denotar las cadenas, (array de `char`, `char[]` en C).

Por otro lado `struct.pack_into` sirve para escribir en un buffer, necesita dos parámetros posicionales extra que siguen al formato, `buffer` y `offset` (indica la posición a partir de la cual escribir).

Si no vas a escribir los datos en un buffer, usa `struct.pack`:

```
import struct


i = 1
string1 = 'AAAA'
string2 = 'BBBB'

a = struct.pack("!I4s4s", i, string1.encode(), string2.encode())
```

Ten en cuenta que un entero (`I` (unsigned) e `i` (signed)) tiene un tamaño de 4 `char`. Si `char` ocupa un byte (generalmente), el entero ocupa siempre cuatro bytes y no uno como muestras en tu salida esperada y su valor máximo depende de este tamaño.